# How can I convert RGB hex value into UIColor in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftify

I tried converting the following Objective -C code block to Swift using Swiftify.

```
#define HEXCOLOR(hex) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16)) / 255.0 green:((float)((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8)) / 255.0 blue:((float)(hex & 0xFF)) / 255.0 alpha:1]
```

This code is called as:

```
_contentView.backgroundColor = HEXCOLOR(0x24B491);
```

Here is the converted code output

```
func HEXCOLOR(_ hex: Any) -> UIColor {
    UIColor(red: CGFloat((Float((hex & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 255.0), green: CGFloat((Float((hex & 0xff00) >> 8)) / 255.0), blue: CGFloat((Float(hex & 0xff)) / 255.0), alpha: 1)
}
```

The code conversion seems correct in all parts except for the type of the function's input parameter.

P.S. There are many GitHub [gists](https://gist.github.com/Sorix/36436b33537192e60ca3948dbbd48131) which convert hexString to UIColor.

Comment: `func hexColor(_ hex: UInt) -> UIColor {` Btw no need to convert the values to `Float`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks it works perfectly, please post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your hex parameter type from Any to unsigned integer. Btw no need to convert the values to Float.

```
func hexColor(_ hex: UInt) -> UIColor {
    UIColor(red: .init((hex & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255,
          green: .init((hex & 0xff00)   >>  8) / 255,
          blue:  .init( hex & 0xff)            / 255,
          alpha: 1)
}
```

---

```
hexColor(0x24B491)   // r 0.141 g 0.706 b 0.569 a 1.0
```